# Casting Int database value into CoreData issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, core-data

I am trying to load some values from my firebase database directly into CoreData, the value in question is an integer but the issue is CoreData wants a Int64, Int32, or Int16, and it's not possible to downcast Ints in swift, So I am getting an error on the line of code where I assign the CoreData attribute to the database value. The database returns `0` (value will only be 0 or 1). Casting the database value as an Int64 is giving me an error. The bilateral_unilat attribute is of type Int64. How can I save an Int value into CoreData?

```
cdExercise.bilat_unilat = (exercise.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as! Int64)
```

this is the error:
`Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x7fff87a91958) to 'NSNumber' (0x7fff87b50b80).`

in the debugger window I can print out a value of `0`, which is the expected value, with this line of code:

`po (exercise.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as! NSNumber)`

Not sure what the issue is here

Comment: TL;DR The end result was a typo in the OP's database. One of the values being read was a String, not an Int. This could have been more quickly identified by invoking proper handling of optionals - one solution was a nil-coalescing operator as shown in my my answer. *as? Int ?? 0*

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to get to a NSNumber as the end result, here's a couple of options

```
let aInt = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as? Int ?? 0
let aNum = NSNumber(integerLiteral: aInt)
```

or just do it directly

```
let aNum = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as! NSNumber
```

*note I omitted error handling for brevity and assumes the value of the bilat_unilat node is in fact an Int

Comment: I tried and got the following error ```Cannot assign value of type 'NSNumber' to type 'Int64'```

Comment: @NoahIarrobino The code in my answer will not generate that error. Where are you using Int64? And more importantly, is the value of bilat_unilat an int? I suspect you have additional code involved.

Comment: @NoahIarrobino I am pretty sure I addressed the issue in this answer - for future readers, the answer was that one of the values in the node being read was in fact not an Int, which was causing the error. *assumes the value of the bilat_unilat node is in fact an Int*

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x7fff87a91958) to 'NSNumber' (0x7fff87b50b80)

is misleading.

---

`value` is apparently `NSNumber` so cast it to `NSNumber` and then to `Int64`

```
let bilatUnilat = exercise.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as! NSNumber
cdExercise.bilat_unilat = bilatUnilat as! Int64
```

If the value is only 0 or 1 I recommend to declare the attribute as `Bool`

```
let bilatUnilat = exercise.childSnapshot(forPath: "bilat_unilat").value as! NSNumber
cdExercise.bilat_unilat = bilatUnilat == 1
```

And please name the Core Data attributes according to the naming convention *lowerCamelCased*

Comment: The value from the database  is returning an Int, I tried this and got the expected error ```Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff87a90be8) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87b502e8).```

Comment: Then the error message containing `NSTaggedPointerString` is not related to the code

Comment: PS: The *string* error might  occur in the line above

Comment: I don't think it is, here's that line ```cdExercise.exerciseID = exercise.key```, exerciseID is a string as well as the key

Comment: The issue was one of the exercise entities in my DB contained string values for  bilateral_unilat while the rest were  integers, completely user error here